# Is there any tool that can show how a CSS property is computed, if it's not inherited or set directly on the element?

Tags: css, web-inspector

If I have a table cell that's X pixels high, can I see what exactly makes it so – whether it's the height of a sibling `<td>` or it has a child `div` somewhere with the height of X pixels?

Basically, I have [image: this] and I want to see why it's 172 pixels and not, say, 150. The height is never set explicitly in code.

Is there a browser extension somewhere that shows this kind of thing, and saves me the trouble of clicking through each child/sibling node to inspect it CSS?

Edit: I already know that most browsers have built-in DOM inspectors. However, not all CSS attributes are inherited or set directly on the element, as I've said in my first paragraph. I'd like to know if there is a better tool that shows the way an attribute is computed.

Comment: Inspect the browser elements, you can use Chrome, FF, IE.. any browser pretty much. No extensions needed. Press F12.

Comment: in chrome debugger console, you can see the styles of your tr to the right. You will atleast know if there is height property set on tr or not or if it's inherited.

Comment: @JoshC Yes, I know I can do that. However, it's not always convenient to use, if the CSS attribute is not inherited or set directly on the element. I've given the example of the `height` attribute of a table cell, which can be determined by either one of its child elements, or by the height of another sibling `td`, or by the height of the whole table etc.

Comment: @Mihai, correct me if I'm wrong. My understanding is that the question is not about CSS but rather about DOM Element properties, size in particular. 
So to paraphrase, is there any web developer tool that would highlight all children of a selected HTML element with respective size-related properties (height/width/padding/margin/position)?

Comment: This is a HUGE problem with web development.  I want to see a tool that walks the CSS tree, and graphically displays the evaluated properties and which classes they come from, which classes override which, and which specify non-overridable `!important` settings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no easy way to narrow down which element is causing a parent element to change its height. Depending on the situation, it could be a direct style applied to the parent element, it could be one child, or many of the children combined. Most browsers have tools built-in or available via an Add-on that can help make the task of tracking down the problematic style easier, but not quite "easy."

- Firefox
- <strike>Use Firebug,</strike> Hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, make sure you're on the Inspector tab and click on the arrow with a box to the left of the Inspector tab and select the element. Styles will be displayed on the right, and broken down into categories such as directly applied styles, and inherited styles from a parent element.
- Internet Explorer
- Hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, click on the cursor icon and select the element. It will render a treeview of the directly applied styles and the inherited ones.
- Google Chrome
- Hit <kbd>F12</kbd>, the display of the styles will be similar to that of Firebug.

Note that in Firebug, when you have the selection tool enabled, it will outline the element under your cursor showing you on the page the how large the element is (as if you applied a `border: 2px solid blue` style to it. It will also highlight the respective element in the HTML inspector so you know exactly which element you're dealing with. While this isn't going to magically say "oh hey, this particular element and style is the one giving you problems" it will help you get a clearer visual on the problem.

Comment: Perhaps I should have made my question clearer, although I'm not sure how. [Take a look at this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaeVF/) See how the height of the table is determined by the height of the inline text in the second paragraph? How is a DOM inspector helpful in this situation, if the height is never stated explicitly? I can see the computed value, but not how it was computed. In a simple example like this one, you can tell at a glance, but if you have a hierarchy of 50, 60 elements, how do you find the culprit easily?

Comment: @Mihai, see revised answer

Comment: Yeah, I suspected as much. Oh well. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: I seem to be stuck in these situations all the time. I'm surprised they're not common enough for these tools to answer the question 'why is this element this size?'. It would be helpful even if these debugging tools indicated whether an element is being stretched to fill its container, or to contain its child nodes.

Comment: One clue in Chrome, it seems, is that if an element is stretched to fill its container, its width or height display is faded under the 'Computed' tab. This seems true least if its container is stretched because it has a larger sibling. I don't suppose anybody's found clear documentation for these things, have they? (Yeah, I know. 'Google' and 'documentation' look funny in the same sentence.)

Answer (score 2):

### TreeWalker

Typically I would just highlight the nodes in the DOM tree in the developer console however I occasionally come across oddities with `height` myself so this will be a nice tool to have at my disposal from this point onward. There were some technicalities to consider how this works:

- You *have* to use a TreeWalker, things like `childNodes` only apply to the first generation of descendants though not also *their* child nodes.
- You need need to use `scrollHeight`. Things like `getComputedStyle` will return the visually rendered height though not the *fully rendered height*.
- I wrote this to `return false` if there are no descendant elements.
- While not built in to any browser consoles that I know of (*yet*) this at least does *not* depend on any frameworks or libraries.

To use just call something such as `element_find_descendant_tallest(document.getElementById('test1'));`.

---

```
function element_find_tallest_descendant(e)
{
 var walker = document.createTreeWalker(e,NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,null,false),
 height_current = 0;
 tallest = false;

 while (walker.nextNode())
 {
  var n = parseInt(walker.currentNode.scrollHeight);

  if (n != 'NaN' && n > height_current)
  {
   height_current = n;
   tallest = walker.currentNode;

   //Update console every time new tallest descendant found:
   console.log(walker.currentNode);
   console.log(n);
   console.log('---');
  }
 }

 return tallest;
}
```

Comment: Thank you John!♥  I think many cases are not covered by this, for example when the (parent) element’s width results from the _sum_ of the widths of (some of) its children;  or when the element’s size is determined by an ancestor;  but it’s a good piece of work that will surely be helpful in some cases.  You deserve some rep gingerbread! :D

Comment: @AaronThoma LoL thank you Aaron. If you want I'm up to the challenge if you post a new question with specifics and then link it back here in these comments. It's usually fairly easy to make highly dynamic functions. Also, if you'd like my existing treasure trove visit my site in my profile and then go to the JavaScript Documentation page. The JavaScript function names are dynamically detected and a large number have documentation via on-demand JavaScript. ︀

Comment: re making functions challenge:  Cool, thanks man!! \*cowboy hat tip*  Some day i might just try and see if that offer still stands. :)  To cover all edge cases (pun) would be very complicated though, i believe.  If someone wants to tackle that anyway, I think it would be best to delve into the source code of Blink (or another browser engine) and trace its calculation of element dimensions (which are then displayed in the DevTools in light grey, visible in the screenshot in the Question above).

Comment: @AaronThoma I try to update documentation whenever I can and at some point I'll be doing a major audit of every single JavaScript function. DAD is short for drag and drop since I don't want excessively long prefixes for function names and yeah, I don't think I noticed that one before. Being the late 2010s and early 2020s we now have sufficient amount of JavaScript to tackle about 95% of what I want to do if I could simply pause time and I plan on eventually building my own browser/engine/OS with the important things not currently taken in to consideration by current software. ︀

Comment: @AaronThoma My next task is to use the Treewalker to find all text nodes in HTML email and then (because I refuse to use an `iframe` and use the XML parser instead of the HTML parser) will determine what the `background-color` is and therefore if the given text node has enough visual contrast. Many emails require dozens of fixes that I've already programed and modifying an email requires a note when replying, forwarding or referencing. Here is an excellent video about IR and what I do naturally: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LvpjwHT7o4I